# is it possible to make ethanol from ethane through a chlorination / hydrolysis two-step procedure?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

1. $\ce{C2H6}$ is chlorinated in presence of sunlight to form $\ce{C2H5Cl}$ and $\ce{HCl}$.
2. $\ce{C2H5Cl}$ is then reacted with water to form $\ce{C2H5OH}$ + $\ce{HCl}$

Comment: Can someone please confirm this???

Comment: Fundamentally possible, but pretty uneconomic on both stages.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Especially the first stage. The yield there will be awful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Although ,commercially(and ironically!) alkyl halides are produced from the corresponding alcohols.
The main reason why this is so because free-radical chlorination requires high temperatures and catalysts to promote the reaction.

Theoretically, the first reaction will give good yields(and not a mixture unlike most free radical halogenations because of the simple reactant involved)

Edit:As pointed out by bon, I forgot to take into account that because its a free radical reaction, the number of possible products is a lot.So no, the first reaction will not give you good yields.

Comment: The first reaction will give terrible yields. Multiple chlorinations are highly likely and there is also the possibility of a variety of other radical reactions.

Comment: :/....I don't know why I didn't take it into account.Thanks for pointing it out :)